# Upgrade to AndroidX - TextViews and EditTexts not displaying text unless color is specified

Tags: android, material-design, androidx

I just migrated to androidx and all my editTexts and textViews that use that default textcolor will not be displayed unless I specify a textcolor. Also the editText underlines do not show as well.

**This is from the preview:**

[image]

**On emulator:**

[image]

**I had to specify the textview location color to the default edittext color of #808080 for it to show**

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/fragform_textview_location"
   android:layout_width="90dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Location"
   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
   android:textColor="@color/defaultTextColor"/>
```

Before the androidx migration I didn't have to do this. Is it now necessary to manually type the default text color for each textview + edittext for it to show? How do I get the edittext underline to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your activity theme. it might be the cause.

Comment: Theme was on Theme.MaterialComponents causing the issue